# How do you open a bottle like this?

Tags: food

[image: pic1]

[image: pic2]

I bought this bottle of fish sauce and cannot seem to find a proper way to open it. Tried some methods but so far all failed 1: using my fingernails to pull the translucent plastic cork upward; 2: unscrewing the whole yellow cap with absolutely brutal force (apparently the translucent cork itself blocks the unscrewing); 3: use scissors to cut off the translucent cork (this one probably could eventually make an opening if you are persistent enough to trim off everything. However, I suspect there is a proper and cleaner method to open this bottle). Can someone suggest a method to open it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Googling around, I found these tips, which all basically say to **slice off the inside cover**.

- Take a sharp knife and carefully slice off the plastic top. I used a steak knife and slowly cut it. I was tempted to hack it up into pieces, but I had to control my rage so I don’t accidentally stab myself.
  [- Diana Chan, foodology.ca](http://foodology.ca/open-bottle-golden-boy-brand-fish-sauce/)
- I am not alone in being somewhat puzzled by how to open the Golden Boy fish sauce bottles.  The punchline is to take a knife and to cut off the raised "nipple" so that you have an opening.
  [- comradechufood](http://comradechufood.blogspot.com/2010/01/i-should-not-need-to-google-how-to-open.html)
- Do you mean after flipping the cap back? Many have that little nipple thing that needs to be cut off
  [- Candy, Chowhound](https://www.chowhound.com/post/opening-fish-sauce-307652)

Comment: Thx, I just cut out the"nipple" to make a hole lol

Answer (score 0):

They wouldn't make all that just so you would cut it off.  I'd suggest poking a hole with a needle.

Comment: Some hole, you'd need to use a knitting needle! Just cut the nippl off (not the whole clear plastic part, just the little sticking-up part on top of the clear plastic part)